# Rename multiple files from directory name

Tags: file, rename, mv

I have multiple directories with multiple files on each. Each file on each directory follows the same structure.

```
enter code here

.
├── one
│   ├── alpha.yaml
│   └── beta.yaml
├── three
│   ├── alpha.yaml
│   └── beta.yaml
└── two
    ├── alpha.yaml
    └── beta.yaml
```

I would to rename all files with their relevant directory name, ie:

```
.
├── one
│   ├── one_alpha.yaml
│   └── one_beta.yaml
├── three
│   ├── three_alpha.yaml
│   └── three_beta.yaml
└── two
    ├── two_alpha.yaml
    └── two_beta.yaml
```

I tried some for loop commands but these are deleting:

`for i in *; do mv "$i/_alpha.yaml" "$i/$i_alpha.yaml" ; do`

Comment: You can do it in python

Comment: any clue how in python?

Comment: Use os.rename:

`import os

os.rename('a.txt', 'b.txt')`

Comment: If you need the complete script for your case I'll post an answer

Comment: can you append the complete script?

Comment: Sure, just a minute

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using os.rename in python:

```
import os

basepath = './'
for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(basepath):
   for singleFile in filenames:  
       os.rename(singleFile, dirname + '_' + singleFile)
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: do I have to change anything on it or runs in one go?

Comment: It should run. The only clause is that this python file must be in you root folder

Comment: why in root directory? what if this change any other file?

Comment: for root directory i mean this . folder: .
`├── one
│   ├── alpha.yaml
│   └── beta.yaml
├── three
│   ├── alpha.yaml
│   └── beta.yaml
└── two
    ├── alpha.yaml
    └── beta.yaml`

Comment: the folder in which there are _one_ , _two_ and _three_

Comment: > cat rename.py
        #!/usr/bin/env python2
        import os
        
        basepath = './back'
        for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(basepath):
           for singleFile in filenames:
               os.rename(singleFile, dirname + '_' + singleFile)
        
        
        > python2 rename.py
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "rename.py", line 7, in <module>
            os.rename(singleFile, dirname + '_' + singleFile)
        OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Check if singleFile has extension using print(singleFile)